# No way to update web hook Subscriptions with MS graph

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, webhooks, sharepoint-online

In a console app running with app only credentials,
I get a Subscriptions like so:

```
var list = await graphClient.Sites[site.Id].Lists["My list name"].Request().GetAsync();
                    var subs = await graphClient.Sites[site.Id].Lists[list.Id].Subscriptions.Request().GetAsync();
                    foreach (var sub in subs)
                    {
                        if ((sub.ExpirationDateTime - DateTime.Today).Value.Days < 60)
```

Then I want to extend for future date using:

```
Subscription subscription = new Subscription
         { ExpirationDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2020-11-01T00:00:00.9356913Z")  };
var newSub = await graphClient.Sites[site.Id].Lists[list.Id].Subscriptions[sub.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(subscription);
```

This gives me an Error :

### 500 - Internal server error.

#### There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

and if I use just the Subscription ID like so:

```
var newSub = await graphClient.Subscriptions[sub.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(subscription);
```

I get an error: "Code: ResourceNotFound   Message: The object was not found."

How then can I extend the Subscriptions?
If they will expire, other things will stop working too.

Maybe it is Graph permissions but I did not see any Subscriptions related permission in the Azure portal.

Thank you

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using? Beta or v1?

Comment: Whatever <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="3.8.0" /> is targeting

Answer (score 1):

`graphClient.Subscriptions` gives you access to [Microsoft Graph change notifications subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/subscription?view=graph-rest-1.0) (aka webhooks). `graphClient.Sites[siteid].Lists[listid].Subscriptions` [gives you access to socket.io streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscriptions-socketio?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

As you're building a dotnet application my guess is that you're interested in webhooks so any subscription operation should be done with `graphClient.Subscriptions`.

Comment: But graphClient.Subscriptions brings an empty results set. graphClient.Sites[site.Id].Lists["My list name"].Request().GetAsync(); brings the Subscriptions I know I made before with logic app. So how do I extend the expiration date?

Comment: those are two different kinds of subscriptions. The socketio one doesn't have a notion of renewing the expiration as far as I know.